# Suppose $n$ denotes a non negative integer. Determine the values of $n$ such that $z^n=1$ possesses only real solutions.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $n$ denotes a non negative integer. Determine the values of $n$ such that $z^n=1$ possesses only real solutions.

**My attempt:**

Let $w\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $w=\cos0+i\sin0$. and $z=p(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$

Note $z^n=w$. This implies:

$p^n(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=r(\cos 0+i\sin 0)\iff p^n=r\text{ and}\, (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=\cos0+i\sin0$

Then,

$p=(r)^\frac{1}{n}$

$\cos (n\theta)=\cos 0$ and $\sin n\theta=\cos 0$

This implies:

$n\theta=0+2k\pi\implies \theta=\frac{2k\pi}{n}$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

As $k=0,...,n-1$ then we obtain $n$ distint values such that $z^n=1$

In other words,

$z_k=r^\frac{1}{n}(\cos \frac{2k\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{n})$
for $k=0,...,n-1$

Is this correct?

Comment: The end result should be $n=1,2$.

Comment: Why? @RushabhMehta Can be more specific? thanks

Comment: The solutions to $z^n=1$ where $n\in\mathbb N$ are of the form $e^{2ik\pi/n}$ where $0\leq k<n$. This is rather easy to show, and this explains my above contention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be real, we need

$$\sin\left(\frac{2k \pi}n \right)=0$$

That is we need $\frac{2k}{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $k=1$, we need $\frac2n \in \mathbb{Z}$, the factors of $2$ are $1$ and $2$. Check that for $n \in \{1,2\}$ has real solution (which should be easy).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your clear answer.